# Do I have a current enough version of Eclipse via my PHP Development Tools installation?

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-pdt

Today I installed the [PHP Development Tools](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) package, but I see my Eclipse version is only  3.0.2, while Eclipse Classic is already RTM'd at 3.7.1.

I understand the version numbers are not from the same line, but I am a little concerned that I may be missing out quite a lot. Can anyone shed some light what the differences are here, and whether it might be possible to migrate the PHP 'stuff' into a more mainstream Eclipse version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They seem to use their own project numbering.

If you check the review section they seem to run with Eclipse Indigo (3.7).
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=197633 so you should be up to date.